Does Pure Land Buddhism only acknowledge the 3 sutra in its canon?
On this website, it is stated:

The Pure Land tradition is founded on three sutras and two commentaries: the Sutra on Immeasurable Life, also known as the Larger Pure Land Sutra; the Amida Sutra, also known as the Smaller Pure Land Sutra; and the Contemplation Sutra. The two commentaries are Vasubandhu’s Treatise on the Sutra of Immeasurable Life and Shandao’s Commentary on the Contemplation Sutra.

Assuming someone acknowledges the Āgama and its form of the Pali canon, are the 3 sutras the only sutras that are, let's say "mandatory" for Pure Land Buddhism, while the rest of the Mahayana sutras are optional? Or are other sutras held as canonical and also "mandatory" to acknowledge and believe in?

Your question, last paragraph needs reformatting. I cant really understand what you are asking.

@Remyla My bad. So basically, Pure Land acknowledges the Pali canon in the form of Agama, right? Well, to be a form of Mahayana as well as to be "Pure Land", it also acknolwedges certain Mahayana sutra. In the case of Pure Land, its the 3 sutras named in the question. Without those sutras, you really can't be a Pure Lander, so they're considered mandatory and canonical for Pure Land Buddhism. I am asking whether this is the case for ONLY those 3, or if there are other Mahayana sutras which are also considered canonical and mandatory for a Pure Lander, or if they're optional e.g. Lotus Sutra.

I dont know the sect correctly but I would assume they use the prajnaparamita, diamond, lotus and heart sutra in their teachings, maybe even more. These are pretty much fundamental to mahayana.
